# In Power BI SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR not working when date slicer style is in between or before

Tags: powerbi-desktop

In Power BI SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR function not working when date slicer style is in  between or before
It is giving current data only

It has to give previous year data